# Filter directory listing in pyftpdlid

Tags: python, ftp

In pyftpdlid how to filter the list of directories returned based on specific conditions, I want to hide some directories and files.I think it may be related to the 'def ftp_LIST(self, path):' method. I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to:

- Derive a class from [`AbstractedFS`](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyftpdlib.filesystems.AbstractedFS).
- Reimplement its [`listdir` method](https://pyftpdlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyftpdlib.filesystems.AbstractedFS.listdir).
- Assign your implementation of `AbstractedFS` to `FTPHandler.abstracted_fs`.

```
class FilteredFS(AbstractedFS):
    def listdir(self, path):
        files = os.listdir(path)
        # filter as you need
        return files

handler = FTPHandler
# ...
handler.abstracted_fs = FilteredFS
server = FTPServer(('', 21), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```